# Preseeding the installer using all already existing Linux partitions and all free space

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, preseed

I need to preseed a dual boot installation of Ubuntu 10.04. I want partman to use all already existing Linux partitions and all free space (like the option when installing Fedora 13).

What would that recipe look like?

Answer (score 2):

You need an unattended install. A couple of approaches here:

- [Ubuntu help wiki page on unattended installation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UnattendedCD)
- [A quick guide to unattended Ubuntu installations (using Kickstart)](https://web.archive.org/web/20160712072046/http://www.linuxuser.co.uk/tutorials/unattended-ubuntu-installations) - see also [the Ubuntu help wiki Kickstart documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KickstartCompatibility)

Comment: The information provided on the ubuntu preseed page ( https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/installation-guide/powerpc/preseed-using.html ) does not include examples to do what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you cannot reuse partitions, you only can use the space left non partitioned or use the whole disk (deleting all the data living in the disk), you're looking for the options:

```
 # other possible choices: regular, lvm, crypto
 d-i    partman-auto/method string regular

 # other possible choices: atomic, home, multi
 d-i     partman-auto/choose_recipe select multi

 #d-i     partman-auto/expert_recipe string 
 # http://edwardpku.com/cun/2008/05/05/partman-auto-recipe-files/
```